# How can I get apps in Plasma desktop to look right on a very large screen? There's no desktop scaling option

Tags: kde, zooming

I just started using the KDE launcher instead of the Unity launcher in Ubuntu 16.04. It looks very nice, but, since I have a very large screen (4k, indeed), the UI elements look very small. In Unity launcher, there was a setting for this. In KDE, you can't directly magnify the desktop, but you can change the font size, etc. However, I have had a little trouble with scaling apps like Chrome. Is magnifying the UI of Chrome possible, or do I need to use another browser?

[image: A screenshot]

Edit: since I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, my version of KDE is 5.18.0

Comment: You might consider upgrading to Kubuntu 20.04 (do a fresh install instead of upgrading), and use fractional scaling. Are you sure you are using KDE Plasma 5.18.0? Ubuntu 20.04 came with that. 16.04 must have a much older version

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to scale. It won't. KDE hasn't put much of an effort into working with 4K monitors if you need it to scale to where you can actually see text as text and not very thin lines. And if you want to have multiple monitors with different resolutions, just forget about it. I'm sure the small number of people actually working on it are working on it. There just seems to be more emphasis on a lot of people making cool stuff and not stuff that actually helps it work better.